# Question about match_recognize syntax with esper CEP

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am using the match_recognize syntax when doing CEP querying with esper. I noticed that after matching some events it ignores them for future matches. for example if using the simple following pattern:

```
select * from Event
match_recognize (
measures A as a, B as b, C as c
pattern (A B C)
)
```

it would match the events number 1,2 and 3 in the stream. After that it would match the events number 4,5 and 6. But I want it to match 1,2,3 and then events number 2,3,4 and then 3,4,5 and so forth (of course I'll add more conditions later). 
Is there some simple adjustement to this syntax that could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `after match skip` in the syntax. [doc link](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.4.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#match-recognize-syntax)

```
match_recognize (
  ...
  after match skip to current row
  pattern (...)
)
```